# Use custom build output folder when using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Facebook provides a `create-react-app` [command](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to build react apps. When we run `npm run build`, we see output in `/build` folder.

> npm run build
>
> Builds the app for production to the build folder. It correctly
>   bundles React in production mode and optimizes the build for the best
>   performance.
>
> The build is minified and the filenames include the hashes. Your app
>   is ready to be deployed!

How can we use custom folder instead of `/build` for the output? Thanks.

Comment: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448851/how-do-i-change-src-folder-to-something-else-in-create-react-app/48590867#48590867) and try change 'build' to 'whatever'. Haven't tried it.

Comment: this is officially supported now, scroll down to https://stackoverflow.com/a/62378644/214446

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Edit: Support for a configurable `BUILD_PATH` just landed into v4.0.2. See [t_dom93's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66036117/1333836).

You can't change the build output folder name with the current configuration options.

Moreover, you shouldn't. This is a part of [the philosophy behind `create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#philosophy): they say **Convention over Configuration**.

If you really need to rename your folder, I see two options:

1. Right after the build process finishes, **write a command that copies the build folder content to another folder you want**. For example you can [try the `copyfiles` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles), or anything similar.
2. You could try to [eject create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) and tweak the configuration.

> If you aren’t satisfied with the build tool and configuration choices, you can eject at any time. This command will remove the single build dependency from your project.

> Instead, it will copy all the configuration files and the transitive dependencies (Webpack, Babel, ESLint, etc) right into your project so you have full control over them. All of the commands except eject will still work, but they will point to the copied scripts so you can tweak them. At this point you’re on your own.

However, it is important to note that **this is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back**! You loose all future updates.

Therefore, **I'd recommend you to not use a custom folder naming, if possible**. Try to stick with the default naming. If not an option, try #1. If it still doesn't work for your specific use-case and you're really out of options - explore #2. Good luck!

Comment: what advantage would copying the files have over renaming the folder?

Comment: my main concern was that it might cause troubles if any of the other `react-create-app` commands is using the `/build` folder for input. (example: during the deploy process). So copying is the safest option I see.

PS: If there are no plans for using the the default `/build` folder for input, I agree with you - just renaming it will do the same trick.

Comment: Same for me.  I'd like my build folder to go somewhere else so I can create a Docker image without all the other cruft in the root folder to have to be excluded from the docker context.

Comment: The problem with convention over configuration is if you have multiple colliding conventions. IE we use react inside an angular application. So only the final build should go into build and react creates just intermediate files.

Comment: This has landed with version `v4.0.2`. Working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66036117/6774916

Comment: "Convention over Configuration" doesn't mean inflexible.

Comment: They figured out "Convention over Configuration" wasn't good enough and implemented it on `v4.0.2`

Comment: The accepted answer should be @t_dom93 now

Answer (score 187):

With `react-scripts >= 4.0.2`, this is [officially supported](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration):

> By default, Create React App will output compiled assets to a `/build` directory adjacent to `/src`. You may use this variable to specify a new path for Create React App to output assets. `BUILD_PATH` should be specified as a path relative to the root of your project.

```json
// package.json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "BUILD_PATH='./dist' react-scripts build",
    // ...
  },
```

or adding a .env file to the root of your project:

```sh
# .env
BUILD_PATH='./dist'
```

**Caution**: the path specified in `BUILD_PATH` will be wiped out without mercy. Double check that your environment variable is specified correctly, especially when using continuous integration.

Comment: I hope it gets in! This is super annoying that they refuse to support it.

Comment: This configuration was published today with version 4.0.2, it's on the advanced configuration docs and the changelog.

Comment: This solution is great!  **Important warning** When writing a BUILD_PATH make sure that the path you write doesn't exist or you don't mind be erased. Doing `BUILD_PATH='..'` made some serious damage to progress I made on my project. (It deleted git as well.)

Comment: For windows, you need to use set. For example:
`"build": "set BUILD_PATH=../wwwroot/clientapp && react-scripts build"`

Comment: This way is the best when used on both Windows & Mac environments

Comment: To expand on Dan's answer: On Windows you need to use "set" before BUILD_PATH. You can NOT use '' around the path. You also have to remember the && before react-scripts.

Comment: "'BUILD_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"??

Comment: Warning! You can inadvertently create folders with a space at the end which can be difficult to delete in Windows. Escape the quotes:

`"build": "set \"BUILD_PATH=../my_path/to_somewhere\" &&  react-scripts build"`

If you are having difficulty deleting the folder you can use cmd:
`rd /s "\\?\C:\project\my_path\to_somewhere "`

Answer (score 142):

Edit your package.json:

```
"build": "react-scripts build && mv build webapp"
```

Comment: I had to make it `"build": "react-scripts build && rm -rf docs && mv build docs"` otherwise after the first run it moves the build _into_ the docs folder instead of overwriting it.

Comment: The commands equivalent for Windows ``rm -rf webapp  =  DEL /S /Q webapp``  and
``mv build webapp  =   move build webapp``

Comment: If you don't want to move build folder, just copy its files. commands equivalent for Windows : ``mv build webapp = xcopy /E /H /C /I build webapp``

Comment: If you want to move have things inside build on webapp and not webapp/build, the commands for Windows are `"build": "react-scripts build && RMDIR /S /Q webapp && move build webapp"`

Comment: To make it run across platforms (including Windows), first install an npm package called [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) using `npm i --save-dev cross-env`. And then, in your package.json: `"build": "cross-env react-scripts build && mv build webapp"`

Comment: Not good for wanting to build for a new environment without touching your current local `build` directory.  This still clobbers that directory.

Comment: For newer versions of react-scripts, see [Andrew H's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62378644/419294)

Answer (score 77):

**Create-react-app Version 2+ answer**

For recent (> v2) versions of create-react-app (and possible older as well), add the following line to your package.json, then rebuild.

```
"homepage": "./"
```

You should now see the build/index.html will have relative links `./static/...` instead of links to the server root: `/static/...`.

Comment: Thanks. This should be the accepted answer. VS Code will warn you if you don't use an absolute URL, but the build works with relative URLs as well.

Answer (score 45):

Support for `BUILD_PATH` just landed into [v4.0.2](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v4.0.2).

Add `BUILD_PATH` variable to `.env` file and run `build` script command:

```
// .env file
BUILD_PATH=foo
```

That should place all build files into `foo` folder.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked as expected with BUILD_PATH=../dist

Answer (score 22):

Félix's answer is correct and upvoted, backed-up by [Dan Abramov himself](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1354#issuecomment-299956790).

But for those who would like to change the structure of the output itself (within the `build` folder), one can run post-build commands with the help of `postbuild`, which automatically runs after the `build` script defined in the `package.json` file.

The example below changes it from `static/` to `user/static/`, moving files and updating file references on relevant files ([full gist here](https://gist.github.com/dreamyguy/358456085528c186124d8908a6927873)):

package.json

```
{
  "name": "your-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  [...]
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postbuild": "./postbuild.sh",
    [...]
  },
}
```

postbuild.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# The purpose of this script is to do things with files generated by
# 'create-react-app' after 'build' is run.
# 1. Move files to a new directory called 'user'
#    The resulting structure is 'build/user/static/<etc>'
# 2. Update reference on generated files from
#    static/<etc>
#     to
#    user/static/<etc>
#
# More details on: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3824

# Browse into './build/' directory
cd build
# Create './user/' directory
echo '1/4 Create "user" directory'
mkdir user
# Find all files, excluding (through 'grep'):
# - '.',
# - the newly created directory './user/'
# - all content for the directory'./static/'
# Move all matches to the directory './user/'
echo '2/4 Move relevant files'
find . | grep -Ev '^.$|^.\/user$|^.\/static\/.+' | xargs -I{} mv -v {} user
# Browse into './user/' directory
cd user
# Find all files within the folder (not subfolders)
# Replace string 'static/' with 'user/static/' on all files that match the 'find'
# ('sed' requires one to create backup files on OSX, so we do that)
echo '3/4 Replace file references'
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | LC_ALL=C xargs -I{} sed -i.backup -e 's,static/,user/static/,g' {}
# Delete '*.backup' files created in the last process
echo '4/4 Clean up'
find . -name '*.backup' -type f -delete
# Done
```

Comment: "postbuild": "postbuild.sh" (without ./) worked for me, at least in windows

Comment: Shame you have to trample `build` and then move / rename it.

Answer (score 10):

I had the scenario like want to rename the folder and change the build output location, and used below code in the package.json with the latest version

```
"build": "react-scripts build && mv build ../my_bundles"
```

Comment: this is very useful when copying the contents of a `build` within a `docs` dir for hosting with github pages, ended up going with,

    `"build-docs": "react-scripts build && cp -r build/** docs"`

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution:
create .env in root, then add this line to it.

```
BUILD_PATH=$npm_package_name-$npm_package_version
```

the build path will be "name_of_app"-"version"

these values could be set in package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.2",
...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Move command for windows did not work for me. Because it does not copy the "static" folder and subfolders. So I was able to solve this problem using 'ROBOCOPY'.

```
"build": "react-scripts build && ROBOCOPY build ../my-relative-path/react-app /E",
```

Comment: This seems the best option for a Windows user - nothing else worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answers by [Ben Carp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app#answer-55833523) and [Wallace Sidhrée](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app#answer-51818028):

This is what I use to copy my entire build folder to my wamp public folder.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "[your project name]",
  "homepage": "http://localhost/[your project name]/",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  [...]
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "postbuild": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./post_build.ps1",
    [...]
  },
}
```

**post_build.ps1**

```
Copy-Item "./build/*" -Destination "C:/wamp64/www/[your project name]" -Recurse -force
```

The homepage line is only needed if you are deploying to a subfolder on your server (See [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183494/create-react-app-build-deploy-on-lamp-xampp-wamp#answer-53816284) from another question).

Answer (score 5):

Quick compatibility build script (also works on Windows):

```
"build": "react-scripts build && rm -rf docs && mv build docs"
```

Answer (score 5):

Using cross-env is the solution.

Install cross-env:

```
npm install cross-env
```

You should update to:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "cross-env BUILD_PATH='../yourCustomBuildFolder' react-scripts build",
}
```

Comment: I was getting BUILD_PATH not recognized error but after applying what you said my problem was solved.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still looking for an answer that works on both Linux and Windows:

Add this to the `scripts` section in `package.json`

```
"build": "react-scripts build && mv build ../docs || move build ../docs",
```

with `../docs` is the relative folder you want to move the build folder to

Answer (score 2):

#### Windows Powershell Script

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "postbuildNamingScript": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./powerShellPostBuildScript.ps1",


// powerShellPostBuildScript.ps1
move build/static/js build/new-folder-name 
(Get-Content build/index.html).replace('static/js', 'new-folder-name') | Set-Content 
build/index.html
"Finished Running BuildScript"
```

Running `npm run postbuildNamingScript` in powershell will move the JS files to `build/new-folder-name` and point to the new location from `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Open Command Prompt inside your Application's source.
Run the Command

> npm run eject

Open your **scripts/build.js** file and add this at the beginning of the file after 'use strict' line

```
'use strict';
....
process.env.PUBLIC_URL = './' 
// Provide the current path
.....
```

[image]

Open your **config/paths.js** and modify the buildApp property in the exports object to your destination folder. (Here, I provide ***'react-app-scss'*** as the destination folder)

```
module.exports = {
.....
appBuild: resolveApp('build/react-app-scss'),
.....
}
```

[image]

Run

> npm run build

Note: *Running Platform dependent scripts are not advisable*

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

1. Change in your `package.json` the script item into `"build": "react-scripts build && mv build webapp"` where `webapp` is your destination folder;
2. Create `.env` file in your root directory and insert in it the new definition of build destination folder (ex. `BUILD_PATH='./data'`)

Answer (score -1):

You can update the configuration with a little hack, under your root directory:

1. npm run eject
2. config/webpack.config.prod.js - line 61 - change path to: __dirname + './../--your directory of choice--'
3. config/paths.js - line 68 - update to resolveApp('./--your directory of choice--')

replace --your directory of choice-- with the folder directory you want it to build on

note the path I provided can be a bit dirty, but this is all you need to do to modify the configuration.

Answer (score -2):

webpack =>

renamed as *build to dist*

```
output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
```