# How do I change `src` folder to something else in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

I'd like to know if it's possible using `react-script` to rename `src` to something else like `app` folder

Comment: Could you tell us more on what you're trying to achieve? You can just use fs.rename or just mv? Do you want to change name of src directory to app and react script to continue working as expected?

Comment: It should be possible, but you will need to eject and change all parts where src occurs in the internals to your new folder name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use custom build output folder when using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app)

Comment: You can use the mv command to move a directory? And here I am just clicking and dragging it in my fancy GUI, but somehow react-script doesn't work anymore but why would I want that? It's not like we're asking questions on a website that helps developers solve problems.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#extended-configuration-options) to override react paths configuration.
    In my case, I can change the paths in **config-overrides.js** file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    paths: function (paths, env) {        
        paths.appIndexJs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'mysrc/client.js');
        paths.appSrc = path.resolve(__dirname, 'mysrc');
        return paths;
    },
}
```

Comment: For anyone using `customize-cra`, you still have to do the same thing. See: https://github.com/goblin-laboratory/cra-multi-page-template/blob/c76ff80a949413ed1f57136b25639d0e39dbd893/config-overrides.js

Comment: for me I had to add following path as well
`paths.appTypeDeclarations = path.resolve(__dirname, 'ui/typings');`

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this answers your question but I'll give it a shot.  My directory structure looks like this:

```
/root
--/app
----/build
----/public
------index.html
----/src
------index.js
app.js
package.js
```

My /root/package.json has this in it:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd app && npm run build",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "serve": "cd app && npm run start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.8.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.17"
  },
```

and my /root/app/package.json looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "set PORT=3000 && react-scripts start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.17"
  }
```

To run the development version of Reactjs, in the /root I can just npm run serve to serve up the dev version.

I am using node and express, so to run the production version of Reactjs, 
in the /root I can just npm run build to create the /root/app/build directory.  I have a router that looks like this:

```
var options = {root : config.siteRoot + '/app/build'};

mainRte.all('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('In mainRte.all Root');
    res.sendFile('index.html', options);
});
```

so when I run /root/app.js in node and surf to "/" it opens up /root/app/public/index.html and then /root/app/index.js.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 5):

[`react-app-rewired`](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) allows for this exact customization.

#### 1

Install `react-app-rewired` as a dev dependency:

```bash
npm install --save-dev react-app-rewired
```

#### 2

In `package.json`, change these lines

```json
"scripts": {
    "react-start": "react-scripts start",
    "react-build": "react-scripts build",
    "react-test": "react-scripts test",
    ...
}
```

to

```json
"scripts": {
    "react-start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "react-build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "react-test": "react-app-rewired test",
    ...
}
```

#### 3

Create a `config-overrides.js` file in your project directory root with the following contents:

```js
const paths = require('react-scripts/config/paths')
const path = require('path')

// Make the "app" folder be treated as the "src" folder
paths.appSrc = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
// Tell the app that "src/index.js" has moved to "app/index.js"
paths.appIndexJs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/index.js')
```

Now your `app` folder is the new `src`!

---

You can also customize many other things, such as the name of the "public" folder:

```js
paths.appPublic = path.resolve(__dirname, 'subfolder/public')
paths.appHtml = path.resolve(__dirname, 'subfolder/public/index.html')
```

And you can also change the location of `package.json` and `node_modules`. See [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js) for the full list.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I'm still gonna post my solution since it might help someone.

I got it working by doing the following:

1. Run `npm run eject`. This exposes some internal configuration stuff from create-react-app
2. Open your `package.json` and edit the respective regexes under `jest.collectCoverageFrom` and `jest.testMatch` to match your test path
3. Alter the paths for `appSrc`, `appIndexJs` and `testsSetup` in the `config/paths.js` file

Comment: This is what glennreyes mentioned in his comment on the question

Comment: I did this without doing `npm run eject` and it dit work so what is really the purpose of that command, is it relevant?

Answer (score 0):

T0astBread's answer is nearly perfect, but there's an additional reference to "src" that he missed inside modules.js.

Specifically:

```
    return {
      src: paths.appSrc,
    };
```

needs to be changed to

```
    return {
      newSrcName: paths.appSrc,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question and a valid scenario for changing this folder name is when migrating old react projects to CRA.

Here's another approach I found that breaks less things:

Create a symlink with:

`ls -s ./app src`

Then add this in `config-overrides.js`, to allow webpack to process the symlink:

```
module.exports = (config, ...rest) => {
    return { ...config, resolve: { ...config.resolve, symlinks: false } };
};
```

Then install `react-app-rewired` and add this to your package.json:

"start": "react-app-rewired start",

Answer (score 0):

While Cong Dan Luong's answer is correct as far as renaming the folder goes, it will **break testing with jest**. You need to expand the **config-overrides.js** module.exports part with the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  jest: function(config) {
    config.collectCoverageFrom = ['client/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', '!client/**/*.d.ts'];
    config.testMatch = [
      '<rootDir>/client/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
      '<rootDir>/client/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    ];
    config.roots = ['<rootDir>/client'];
    return config;
  },

  // The paths config
  paths: function(paths, env) {
    paths.appIndexJs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/index.js');
    paths.appSrc = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client');
    return paths;
  },
};
```

In my above example I am using 'client' instead of 'src'. `npm test` now works.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a symbolic link might address your reasons for wanting to do this:

`ln -s ./src/ ./app`

The `src` folder will remain but you can work with it as if it was the `app` folder.

If, like me you're using vscode you can also do:

`Cmd-shift-p` search workspace settings, and add the following:

```
{
  "files.exclude": {
      "src/": true
  }
}
```

You could do similarly with other editors

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down, it legitimately worked for me for a project at the time...

Comment: Just because something has an intended effect, it doesn't mean that it's the best way to do it. If you have a fly sitting on your desk you can use a newspaper to kill it. You may also use flamethrower or a box of dynamite. These would also kill the fly, but with subtle side effects. And that symbolic link is just bad. And no, I didn't downvote.

Answer (score -3):

Create file in root of your project, insert this code and run.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = './node_modules/react-scripts/config/paths.js';
const folder = 'app';

fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
 if (err) throw err;
 data = data.replace(/src/g, folder);
 fs.writeFile(path, data, 'utf8');
});
```

Comment: This is worse than doing package patches