# Specifying project path with react-scripts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, package.json, react-scripts

I have a react project inside of a folder and I want react-scripts to target and compile from a folder. It looks like this

```
project
│   README.md
│   package.json   
│
└───react
│   │   jsconfig.json
│   │
│   └───src
│   │
│   └───public
│   
└───api
    │   tsconfig.json
    │
    └───src
```

from the `project/package.json` I want to run `react-scripts start` and have it compile the `/react` folder. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with the use off react-app-rewired

See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448851/how-do-i-change-src-folder-to-something-else-in-create-react-app/54625811#54625811) on details of how it was done.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  paths: function (paths, env) {
    paths.appIndexJs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'react/src/index.js');
    paths.appSrc = path.resolve(__dirname, 'react/src');
    paths.appPublic = path.resolve(__dirname, 'react/public');
    paths.appHtml = path.resolve(__dirname, 'react/public/index.html');
    return paths;
  }
}
```