# React Native Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from `` - multiple issues

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

I use this [boilerplate](https://github.com/howtographql/react-apollo). I nearly got `React Native` working on my Android device. But somehow it fails in the last step because it does not find an `index.js` file. But that file is located in my project.

[image: project structure]

So when I now run this in `src/`

```
yarn react-native run-android
```

this is the **Node CLI** window:

[image: node cli window]

So my issue is:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from ``:

None of these files exist:
  * index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

From the console itself I cannot see any issue:

[image: terminal command]

So somehow it does not find the index.js file for some reason.

I already tried `yarn react-native start -- --reset-cache` but it did not change anything.

**Edit #1:**

When I add a fake empty `index.js` file on root folder, the error is gone and in the emulator I get this one:

[image]

**Edit #2:**

I'm getting nearer to a solution. I just added this to the fake `index.js` in the root:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/components/App';
import {name as appName} from './src/app.json';
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

and there I got:

[image]

**Edit #3:**

Now it helped me to overwrite the `app.json` with the following:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "displayName": "test"
}
```

and new error is:

[image]

**Edit #4:**

I now moved all back to the `src` folder. So in the root there is no index.js anymore. Now this works pretty good. The usual `react-scripts start` is running. Also `react-native start` runs. And the issue with `run-android` was fixed with this in the `MainApplication.java`

```
protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
  return "index.android";
}
```

to

```
protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
  return "src/index.android";
}
```

I think this is another issue with the location...

[image: window not found]

Comment: why did you add the index,js in the src folder?

Comment: ps: you can use this template as well it uses typescript (react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript )

Comment: I am new to React. But that Boilerplate said it: https://github.com/howtographql/react-apollo/tree/master/src so that's wrong? And better put it only to the root?

Comment: yes and its better if you use typescript it will make ur life far more easier if the project got a little bigger

Comment: Ok I now switched to TypeScript. But I still have trouble. I get different errors, but most of all it has issues to find the index.js file ```Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: E:\Azure\myapp_werserver_new\src    
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for 
documentation about this command.```

Comment: first get the last react-native cli then run this (react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript )  then navigate to MyApp (or whatever you called it) then run this command npm install

Comment: Yes the MyApp template is running. Here the emulator works. So it's something strange on my code. But was running without issues. Strange behaviour...

Comment: its not that strange actually the packager expects the index.js in root folder in which u register the app

Comment: No, what I mean is. I use `react-scripts start` for the server. But that script is looking under `/src...`. And the usual `react-native start` is looking under root. This is my issue right now. Basically here is a kind of solution. I gonna try to overwrite my location now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448851/how-do-i-change-src-folder-to-something-else-in-create-react-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the **main issue** is fixed relatively easy. All that needs to be done is having a placeholder `App.js` file and another `index.js` file. How to do that in detail [here](https://codersera.com/blog/react-native-web-tutorials-your-first-hybrid-app/). Here is the short description:

First move your existing `App.js` file to `src/App.js`.

Now create a new `App.js` in the main folder:

```
import React from 'react';
import HybridApp from './src/App';
const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <HybridApp />
  );
}
export default App;
```

Also create a new `src/index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

And all the other issues are related to using the wrong technology. Like you cannot use window in React Native. Here the code needs to be rewritten to be working again.