# Could not find required file in react app

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, npm

I have a project which is structured as follows:

```
- my-app
    - src
        - some files
    - public
        - index.html
    - ...
```

If I now execute a `npm start` the application runs as usual.

Now I want to **rename** `src` to `application`!
When I run `npm start` now the following error message appears:

> Could not find a required file. 
> Name: index.js 
> Searched in: C:\Users\{my-user}\my-app\src

Why is it now searching for an `index.js` and why in `my-app/src`?

If I now drag the `public` folder into `application` the following message appears:

> Could not find a required file. 
> Name: index.html 
> Searched in: C:\Users\{my-user}\my-app\public

I know why it can't find the file, but how can I change the path at this point? Is there a setting for this in the index.html or another file?

I would be happy to receive an explanation.

Comment: why do you need to rename the ```src``` folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` path is hardcoded in create-react-app. You'd better keep it, but you can change it : [How do I change `src` folder to something else in create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448851/how-do-i-change-src-folder-to-something-else-in-create-react-app)