# React - Best practice for application with different entry points/sections

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I'm working on a larger React Application right now and have some questions about if I set everything up correct (Best Practice). The application has two different "sections". I'm trying to give an easier example (school scenario) how the structure is set up:

- The first section of the application is used by principal to set up school classes, teachers, students, rooms, etc...
- The section section is used by all the users (teachers, students) that the principal defined. The teachers can set up timetables, etc...

Now what I trying to is: The principal can access his section of the application with the url: admin.school.com - The teachers and students can access the application with the url: school.com

I've put everything in a single react application right now, so I can use the same design, components, etc. During development I switch between the two applications by comment out the application I don't want to access in the `index.js` file:

```
// ReactDOM.render(<AppAdmin />, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My question now is: (How) is it possible that I can get a Build of the application with two "index.html" files so "admin.school.com" points to "admin.html" and "school.com" points to "index.html". My main goal is (like I said) - to have one code basis on my server and just two different html files. Is this possible or do I need to build the application twice? The principal should be able to access the normal section without new login.

I hope that my explanation was easy to understand. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `process.env` to pass environment variables (see https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ if using create-react-app), e.g. in `index.js`:

```
const Component = process.env.REACT_APP_ADMIN ? AppAdmin : App
ReactDOM.render(<Component />, ...)
```

and in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build-admin": "REACT_APP_ADMIN=1 npm run build"
}
```

Comment: So I need two builds? So I build "npm run build-admin" -> put everything from build directory to the folder on the server which points to "admin.school.com". And then the same for "school.com" ?

Comment: if your build system supports custom build directory, use it. otherwise you can move the files to a different directory e.g. by `REACT_APP_ADMIN=1 npm run build && mv build build-admin` as inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/44538829/1176601

Answer (score 0):

You can split React application into several Single Page Applications (SPAs). [Crisp React](https://winwiz1.github.io/crisp-react/) boilerplate supports this functionality. Although it uses TypeScript.

> My question now is: (How) is it possible that I can get a Build of the application with two "index.html" files.

The two .html files can be called differently.
You can have one SPA called `admin` with the entry point (also called landing page) `admin.html`. And another SPA called `school` with entry point `school.html`. All you need for that is to modify the [SPA Configuration](https://winwiz1.github.io/crisp-react/#spa-configuration) block:

```js
var SPAs = [
    new SPA({
      name: "admin",
      entryPoint: "./src/entrypoints/first.tsx",
      redirect: false
    }),
    new SPA({
      name: "school",
      entryPoint: "./src/entrypoints/second.tsx",
      redirect: true
    })
  ];
  SPAs.appTitle = "SchoolApp";
```

and execute `yarn build`. Both SPAs are created for you with .html files. Of course you can write `admin.tsx, school.tsx` and use it instead of `first.tsx, second.tsx`.

> so "admin.school.com" points to "admin.html" and "school.com" points to "index.html".

This is a non-React part.
You create two DNS entries for "admin.school.com" and "school.com", both pointing to the same IP address of your webserver. Let's assume you use NodeJS/Express. In its route handler for `/` e.g. `app.get("/", (req, res, next) => { ... }` examine `req.hostname` and depending on it being either "admin.school.com" or "school.com" make the handler serve `admin.html` or `school.html`.