# How to change default paths of deliverables created by create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

When running `npm run build`, the deliverables are created under `build/static/js`, `build/static/css` and `build/static/media`.

How can I adjust these locations? I found no reference to it in documentation/Google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use custom build output folder when using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app)

Comment: @PrabhatMishra - sadly, yes.

Comment: great than i have this for you https://dev.to/nodewarrior/override-cra-and-add-webpack-config-without-ejecting-2f3n

Comment: use `output` property in webpack.config.js to output your files to your preferred location.

Comment: @PrabhatMishra, I'm not sure how to do that... I assume you mean that I do that in `config-overrides.js`, right? what do I need to write in there?