# How to change outputDir (/build) of TypeScript code in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I am using `create-react-app` with TypeScript template to manage my React project (`yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript`)

When I run `react-scripts build` my code is built into `/build` folder. How to customize this directory?

I tried to change `outDir` of `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`, but this seems ignored by CRA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use custom build output folder when using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems impossible at this moment,

based on the QA: [Use custom build output folder when using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app)

---

There are workarounds, however.

For example, you can build then move it

Inside package.json

```
"build": "react-scripts build && mv build docs"
```

Refer: issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1354

There are many other solutions there, find a suitable one would be good.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `BUILD_PATH` and do as such on Windows `set \"BUILD_PATH=new-folder\" && react-scripts build`