# React build path

Tags: reactjs, build, path

I want to save time, and I want to change the path when I build . Im using craco and this is craco.config.js ( I suppose I have to make some change here )

```
const CracoLessPlugin = require('craco-less');

module.exports = {
    
    plugins: [
        {
            plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
            options: {
                lessLoaderOptions: {
                    lessOptions: {
                        // modifyVars: { '@primary-color': '#1DA57A' },
                        javascriptEnabled: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ],
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Mattia.

You should be able to change the build path on the `package.json` in the "build" script, for example:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "craco start",
   "build": "craco build && mv build whatever-folder-name",
   "test": "craco test"
}
```

**Note:** Please be aware of the [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app) it can bring to your application.

I hope I have understood well your question.

[Source: NPM craco Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco)

Comment: What kind of issues  it can bring? anyway it doesnt work : 
- 'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Hi, Mattia. Could you achieve what you want to? When I have refered about issues I have added a link (in the word issues) from another post for you to have a look, more specifically the one written by Kaloyan Kosev.
About the "mv is not recognized ...", are you using yarn or npm?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BUILD_PATH` environment variabe to set custom
output dir, check [Use custom build output folder when using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app)