# How can I change the directory React looks for the production build?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have created my frontend build using `npm build` and copied it to backend folder. Its path is "backend/build". I ran `npm start` in the backend directory, but nothing is showing up when I navigate to localhost:3001/ and all REST endpoints show 404.

I also get the error:

> "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
> '/home/uradora/mielentilatutkimus-thl/backend/builds/thl/build/index.html'"

So it's looking for:

```
backend/builds/thl/build/index.html
```

when the actual path for the build folder is:

```
backend/build/index.html
```

How do I change the path it's looking for?

Comment: are you sure you meant `npm build` and not "nmp build"?

Comment: yes "npm build" is what I meant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use custom build output folder when using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Create React App you can modify the output with [`BUILD_PATH`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/):

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "BUILD_PATH='./backend/build' react-scripts build",
}
```

to start you can add the path to your script:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "npm start --prefix path/to/your/app",
}
```

Comment: Now the endpoints are returning 200, but nothing is rendered to the screen.

Comment: The status code `200` means success so I would assume you've coded something wrong within your app and is outside the scope of this question.