# React - I can't deploy to github with npm run deploy

Tags: reactjs, git, deployment, vite

first of all I created the repository. then I when to the terminal and typed `git init`, then `git add .`, and
then I took these commands from github and pasted in terminal:
`git commit -m "first commit" git branch -M main git remote add origin https://githubl.com/igora45/ReactShoppingEcommerce.git git push -u origin main`

then I installed the: `npm i gh-pages --save-dev`.
then I went to my `package.json` file and put the `"homepage": "https://igora45.github.io/ReactShoppingEcommerce"`, and then in "scripts" in `package.json` still, I put:
`"predeploy": "npm run build", "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",`

and then, went to the terminal and typed `git add .`, `git commit -m "deploy"`, and then `git push`, and finally the `npm run deploy`.

I'm trying to deploy to github my react app using `npm run deploy` and this is not working since 20 hours that I'm trying to solve this problem

my `package.json`
[PACKAGE.JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb7nS.png)

in my terminal when I write `npm run deploy`:
[TERMINAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIPo2.png)

[My folders, and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbYOA.png)

I tried to delete the "dist" and "dist-ssr" from my `.gitignore` but I was not able to solve this problem.
and I added the `"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"` to my `scripts` in my package.json, but still not works.

I also tried to deploy to netlify, but I have got SEVERAL errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `gh -d build` it means you want to deploy the `build` folder.
But I see that your output folder is `dist` and NOT `build`
Try changing it as `gh-pages -d dist`

Also check that you have enabled `gh-pages` in your GitHub project repo.

1. Go to `settings` tab
2. Select `pages` option from the side menu
3. Set deployment branch as `gh-pages` instead of `master`

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495658/use-custom-build-output-folder-when-using-create-react-app) on custom build output path

Comment: Thanks so much for helped me. Now my application is published. Idk why, but I only can see a white screen instead of my website, but now is published, I will try solve this problem (if you know, and can help me again?). But thanks Vinayak

Comment: but about this error that I said now, I'm seeing this a blank page when I click to see this project that I created and you helped me in published. elements on google developer mode don't show the pages and files that I have in this project.

Comment: Check if this helps [Vite gh-pages](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages). I have never used vite so i can't help any further. Sorry bro